# Correct method to setup iOS constriants

Tags: ios, constraints

I just started using constraints in iOS. I feel fairly comfortable with them, but now I'm wondering what's the proper way to create them. I remember reading to create the constraints in a view's `updateConstraints` method. But I see that doing so could lead to adding multiple copies of the same constraints. Is this true, or will an exact duplicate constraint not be added?

Should my constraints be added in the init and just updated in the `updateConstraints` or is it okay to add and update the constraints in the `updateConstraints` method?

Comment: Generally your constraints should be added in the init and just updated in the updateConstraints, otherwise your constraint will be duplicated. In some case you can check the current constraints and add some missing constraints, but you should not remove any constraint here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from Dave, the answer is to create the initial constraints in the `init`.